Tick Symbol Not Displaying in amCharts TreeMap on Click Event
I'm working on a React application where I am using amCharts to create a TreeMap chart. I want to display a tick symbol next to the name of a node when it is clicked, and remove it when clicked again. However, the tick symbol is not appearing as expected.
Here’s a brief overview of my implementation:
Component Setup: I have a TreeMapChart component that receives chartId and companiesCategories as props.
State Management: I am using a context (usePlan) to manage the state of clicked companies.
Event Handling: I have set up a click event on the nodes of the TreeMap to update the state and change the label text.
Despite setting everything up, the tick symbol does not appear next to the node name when clicked. Additionally, I have added console logs to verify that the click event is firing and the state is updating correctly, but the adapter for the label text does not seem to trigger.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
series.nodes.template.events.on("click", (event) => {
  const dataContext = event.target.dataItem.dataContext;
  const name = dataContext.name;
  const depth = event.target.dataItem.get("depth");

  if (depth === 1) {
    setClickedCompanies((prev) => {
      const newEntry = { type: "company", value: name };
      if (!prev.some((entry) => entry.value === name)) {
        event.target.set("labelText", `[bold]{name}[/] ✔`);
        return [...prev, newEntry]; // Add if not selected
      } else {
        event.target.set("labelText", `[bold]{name}[/]`);
        return prev.filter((entry) => entry.value !== name); // Remove if already selected
      }
    });
  }
});

series.nodes.template.adapters.add("labelText", (text, target) => {
  const name = target.dataItem.dataContext.name;
  const isSelected = clickedCompanies.some((entry) => entry.value === name);
  return isSelected ? `[bold]{name}[/] ✔` : `[bold]{name}[/]`;
});

What I’ve Tried:
Verified that the click event is firing correctly and the correct node is being clicked.
Added console logs to check the state of clickedCompanies.
Simplified the adapter function to see if it runs at all, but the log inside the adapter does not trigger.
Question:
How can I fix the issue so that the tick symbol appears next to the node name when clicked? Is there something I might be missing in the implementation of the adapter or event handling?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)
